# Changing ordering of numeric-style citation call-outs

Tags: biblatex, citing, sorting

I have 4 entries in my .bib file. The first time I use `\cite` in my article it generates `[2]` as the citation call-out. How can I make the first cite I use show `[1]` in the article?

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refbib.bib}
.....
The equation is taken from \cite{A2005} and the graph from \cite{B2006}.
```

and in the numbering I get `[1]` for B2006 and `[2]` for A2005.

Comment: `sorting=none`?

Comment: where do I need to add this? sorry not so familar with it.

Comment: Try `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}`

Comment: @ben - Does changing `\usepackage{biblatex}` to `\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}` help?